# WPF how to manipulate tab sequence by setting index?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, navigation

Now imagine I have ten controls all bound inside a `stackpanel`.

By default, when `TAB` is pressed, the focus will move from control 1 subsequently to control 10. 
Now what I want is, after focus moving from `control 1` to `control 2`, when the user press `TAB` again, the focus will go back to `control 1`. So far I can only mess around with the sequence by using `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="N" where N = "0,1,2,3,.."`, but what I ultimately want is skipping the remaining 8 controls.

**Please do not suggest TabNavigation="NONE" or IsTabStop="False" to skip the control**, I don't want to mess with other controls and yea, I'm fine with hardcode sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the preview key down event on the controls that you want to have control over and if its tab then do what you want.

Here is an example if it was something like a textbox you could use something like this.  Atach the event handlers either in c# or in the xaml.

```
btn1.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(btn1_KeyDown);
btn2.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(btn2_KeyDown);
```

then

```
private void btn1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)))
    {
        //do what you want when shift+tab is pressed.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btn2.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}

private void btn2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)))
    {
        //do what you want when shift+tab is pressed.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btn1.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: @IsaacLem I added an example.

Comment: The main part is I don't know how to move back the focus to control 1.  And all ten controls are button actually.

Comment: @IsaacLem I added example.  Let me know if that helps.